# AngularJS fire ng-change when changing a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
    <form name="deliveryForm" ng-class="{ 'has-error': deliveryForm.$invalid && !deliveryForm.contact.$pristine }">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="controller.order.lines[0].forDelivery" btn-radio="true" ng-change="controller.setDeliveryDetails()">For delivery</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="controller.order.lines[0].forDelivery" btn-radio="false" ng-change="controller.findCollectionPoints()">For collection</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-if="!controller.order.lines[0].forDelivery">
            <label class="control-label">Contact</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contact" ng-model="controller.model.contact" ng-change="controller.setDeliveryDetails()" autocomplete="off" required />
            <input type="hidden" name="collectionPoint" ng-model="controller.model.collectionPoint" ng-change="controller.setDeliveryDetails()" required />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Instructions</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="instructions" ng-model="controller.model.instructions" ng-change="controller.setDeliveryDetails()" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ui-sref="saveOrder.lines">Back</button>
            <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-if="deliveryForm.$valid" ui-sref="saveOrder.confirm">Continue</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, if my first line is **not** for delivery, then I show the contact input and the hidden collectionPoint input.
A bit further down I have a link that changes the collectionPoint:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="controller.model.collectionPoint = point"></a>
```

What I was hoping would happen is that the hidden input would detect the change and fire the **controller.setDeliveryDetails()** method, but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: `ng-model` could be looked at by the `$scope.$watch`. `ng-change` is just not used for that situation.

Comment: a `label` shouldn't have an `ng-model` because the `ng-model` is used on `inputs`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-change is triggered when changes are made on an input not on the model.

What you can do is either run `controller.setDeliveryDetails()` on `ng-click` :

```
<a href="#" ng-click="controller.model.collectionPoint = point; controller.setDeliveryDetails()"></a>
```

Or set up a watch in your controller on controller.model.collectionPoint

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
  return this.model.collectionPoint;
}), function (newVal) {
  controller.setDeliveryDetails();
});
```